# Do Cooper pairs act like Cheshire cats?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, condensed-matter, superconductivity

Could the pairing up of electrons be explained by their spin being in a different position? 
What would separating the spin from an electron in matter do in theory?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, pairing electrons can be spatially separated. In the BCS theory the coherence length $\xi$, also known as the size of the Cooper pair, is the spatial extent over which electrons are expected to pair up. It depends on the material and is given by $$\xi \propto v_{F}/\Delta$$ where $v_{F}$ and $\Delta$ are the Fermi velocity in the normal state and the superconducting gap respectively. For some metals this can be in the microns range, i.e. $\approx 10^4$ times the lattice constant. As a matter of fact, BCS Cooper pairs are **not** “hard core” like a diatomic molecule. Since they extend over such a large distance, copper pairs “overlap.” This can be pictured as the right side of:

[image]

The left side shows the “hard core” paired fermions. One can normally tune between BEC and BCS limits in cold atom experiments.

As for your second question, I think you might be referring to the phenomenon called “spin-charge separation.” The notion of this new phenomenon was studied mostly in the content of high-$T_{c}$ cuprate superconductors. The parent state (i.e. undoped state) of the cuprates form an antiferromagnetic Mott insulator (see figure below).

[image]

In this material, one electron (or hole) is localized to one copper site due to Coulomb repulsion. However, due to the so-called “virtual hopping” of electrons from/to a copper site (blue circle) to/from the oxygen site (pink circle), the spins on nearest neighbor copper sites have opposite spin (see figure above). This is antiferromagnetic configuration is the ground state of the system. A spin flip would raise the energy of the system (i.e. excited state). So instead of exciting electron-hole pairs, like (say) a semiconductor, which carry both spin and charge, excitations in the antiferromagnetic system carry **only** spin; charge is localized to each copper site due to Coulomb repulsion.

Some theories suggest that pairing in cuprate superconductors is mediated by spin fluctuations. A cartoon of this is shown in:

[image]

An electron traveling with a spin up (left) ferromagnetically polarizes the spin medium around it and hence pairs with another traveling spin (right) or vice-versa. According to this theory, this spin fluctuation causes the formation of Cooper pairs instead of electron-phonon interaction, like in BCS.